# show that $P(X=n) = \frac{4}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$ is pmf, that is show that$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} P(X = n) = 1$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions

show that $P(X=n) = \frac{4}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$ is a pmf, that is show that$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} P(X = n) = 1$

My solution

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} P(X = n)$

$ =\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{4}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$

$ =\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} - \frac{1}{n(n+2)}$

$ = 2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{(n+1)}) - (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{(n+2)})$

$ = 2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}  - \frac{1}{(n+1)} + \frac{1}{(n+2)}$

$ = -1$

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second step should be

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{n(n+1)}- \frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)},$$

and then the sum telescopes so we have $2(\frac{1}{2})=1$. The one half comes from the first part of the first term of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}- \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\frac{4}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac 1 2\frac 1n-\frac 1{n+1}  +\frac 12\frac 1{n+2}$$

Hence your partial sums are $$\frac 1 2H_n-(H_{n+1}-H_1)+\frac 1 2 (H_{n+2}-H_2)$$

Using that $H_n=\log n+\gamma+O(1/n)$ you get the result. This generalizes to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{k!}{(n)_k}=\frac{1}{k!k}$$